# Any software similiar to Untangle

Tags: router, open-source, web-filtering

I have currently looked at [Untangle](http://www.untangle.com), I want to know if there are any other similiar projects which have add-on open source projects similiar to what Untangle does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I went with was [Astaro](http://www.astaro.com) and have been very pleased by it.

Comment: but the free edition doesn't seem to have a web filter

Comment: The home license does include a web filter that you can use based on categories or custom urls. If you want web filtering also look into OpenDNS, that and Astaro and you should be set.

Comment: yep i do currently use OpenDNS but was looking for an independent solution that acts like a router and a webfilter this seems to look like a decent alternative to Untangle, i will audition them both and see what best fits the bill. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/)?

Comment: does it have a web filter like untangle? besides i always felt like it was more complicated to use haven't really tried it though u can correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Untangle has a free version, too ... which is opensource, at least they say so.

I am not sure what Untangle does, maybe something like [Guarddog](http://www.simonzone.com/software/guarddog/#introduction) would be what you want.

Comment: Untangle does quite a bit in the free version but im looking out for a more comprhensive web filter and something that offers more features than untangle